# Azure DevOps login via github fails

Tags: github, azure-devops

I get the following error

We cannot complete your request
server_error: The request could not be completed. Please try again later.

Error link:
https://login.live.com/HandleGithubResponse.srf?code=c3f48c4783f6d1d5ef1b&state=38FEE58AB9343DAB#

---

update
I used GitHub to log in to Azure before, and published a [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rxliuli.markdown-extension-pack). Now, when I want to log in to Azure using GitHub, I will be forced to log in to my MS account. My mailbox is rxliuli@gmail.com on both MS and GitHub.
At the same time, I created an organization rxliuli after logging in with an MS account, Azure did not have any errors, but when I want to log in to rxliuli (create a personal token), it will prompt `ERROR Failed request: (401)` What's wrong, is there any way for me to use the publisher name rxliuli after logging in with GitHub before?

[image]

---

update
I can't use vsce to create any new users right now. . .

[image]

---

update
Currently, I can use github to log in to azure, but using `vsce login rxliuli` still shows `ERROR Failed request: (401)`, I am sure that the token has all permissions and has not expired
[image]

Comment: Just to double check can you hit the url shown https://dev.azure.com/org, using the email account you selected in the popup?

Comment: Hi rxliuli any update on this? Have you figured out the issue?

Comment: Unreachable, I don’t know what this url means. . .

Comment: Sorry, the reply was a bit late. I haven't dealt with the issue of vscode extension release in the past few days, so I didn't come to StackOverflow to watch it. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually because the token I created has no choice to allow all organizations. . .

ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#i-get-403-forbidden-or-401-unauthorized-error-when-i-try-to-publish-my-extension